# React JS: ability to detect switching tab in browser

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm sorry if I duplicate the question but I didn't find any solution for my problem.

What is the best way in React to detect switching tabs in browser or hide browser window?

I know there is a [Page visibility API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API) for it but how can I implement it in React component?

Here is the easiest way but I don't know is correct

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Sample extends Component {
  handleBlur = () => {
    console.log('Blur');
  }

  handleFocus = () => {
    console.log('Focus');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div
        style={{ width: 400, height: 200 }}
        onBlur={this.handleBlur}
        onFocus={this.handleFocus}
      >
      test
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Sample;
```

Comment: What have you tried? Could you provide us with some code?

Comment: @zfrisch added a sample

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
let hidden = null;
let visibilityChange = null;
if (typeof document.hidden !== 'undefined') { // Opera 12.10 and Firefox 18 and later support 
  hidden = 'hidden';
  visibilityChange = 'visibilitychange';
} else if (typeof document.msHidden !== 'undefined') {
  hidden = 'msHidden';
  visibilityChange = 'msvisibilitychange';
} else if (typeof document.webkitHidden !== 'undefined') {
  hidden = 'webkitHidden';
  visibilityChange = 'webkitvisibilitychange';
}

class Hello extends React.Component {

  state = {
    actions: []
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    document.addEventListener(visibilityChange, this.handleVisibilityChange, false);
  }

  handleVisibilityChange = () => {
    if (document[hidden]) {
     this.setState({actions: [...this.state.actions, 'hide']});
    } else {
     this.setState({actions: [...this.state.actions, 'show']});
    }
  }

  componentWillUnmount()    {
    document.removeEventListener(visibilityChange, this.handleVisibilityChange);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
      {
        this.state.actions.map((item, key) => <li key={key}>{item}</li>)
      }
    </ul>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Comment: Exectlly as you said I don't want to watch for a focus on div element. 
But how can I apply this solution? I mean I should put this event on some? Because if I just  add this to lifecycles and make a handle function it doesn't work. Please can you provide a working answer?

Comment: I made a mistake also forgot to add browser compatibility, I edited my answer

Comment: nope, it's even doesn't pass into the `handleVisibiltyChange()`
I created a fiddle example with code that you provided. can you see it?
https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/312134/

Comment: I edited code and also put the working example into jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/312210/

Comment: I had a similar question to detect page-load or reload -- it has code example with React Hooks: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67565434/6908282